# Julia: vectorized vs. devectorized code

Tags: arrays, for-loop, vectorization, julia

From what I understood, Julia is supposed to make for loops faster and as fast as vectorized operations. I wrote three versions of a simple function that finds distance using for loops vs. a vectorized operation vs. the latter with DataFrames:

```
x = rand(500)
y = rand(500)
a = rand()
b = rand()

function devect()
    dist = Array(Float64, 0)
    twins = Array(Float64, 0,2)

    for i in 1:500
        dist = [dist; sqrt((x[i] - a)^2 + (y[i] - b)^2)]
        if dist[end] < 0.05
            twins = [twins; [x y][end,:]]
        end
    end

    return twins
end

function vect()
    d = sqrt((x-a).^2 + (y-b).^2)
    return [x y][d .< 0.05,:]
end

using DataFrames

function df_vect()
    df = DataFrame(x=x, y=y)
    dist = sqrt((df[:x]-a).^2 + (df[:y]-b).^2)

    return df[dist .< 0.05,:]
end

n = 10^3

@time for i in [1:n] devect() end
@time for i in [1:n] vect() end
@time for i in [1:n] df_vect() end
```

Output:

```
elapsed time: 4.308049576 seconds (1977455752 bytes allocated, 24.77% gc time)
elapsed time: 0.046759167 seconds (37295768 bytes allocated, 54.36% gc time)
elapsed time: 0.052463997 seconds (30359752 bytes allocated, 49.44% gc time)
```

Why does the vectorized version perform so much faster?

Comment: This might be useful: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vectorization-in-julia

Comment: This may a global scope issue.  Try rewriting your functions so they use local variables rather than global.  That often impacts timings.

Comment: @ptb I originally did that (declared a, b, x, and y inside each function). Didn't help.

Comment: Using inbounds and simd doesn't speed up devect() much.

Comment: Looking a little more closely at your code in devect(), The huge slow down is likely in the way you are constructing your return values.  They start as zero element arrays and then you reassign (i.e. reallocate) them to new arrays at every iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up on my comment about the method used to construct the solution in devect. Here's my code

```
julia> x, y, a, b = rand(500), rand(500), rand(), rand()

julia> function devect{T}(x::Vector{T}, y::Vector{T}, a::T, b::T)
       res = Array(T, 0)
       dim1 = 0
       for i = 1:size(x,1)
           if sqrt((x[i]-a)^2+(y[i]-b)^2) < 0.05
               push!(res, x[i])
               push!(res, y[i])
               dim1 += 1
           end
       end
       reshape(res, (2, dim1))'
   end
devect (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function vect{T}(x::Vector{T}, y::Vector{T}, a::T, b::T)
       d = sqrt((x-a).^2+(y-b).^2)
       [x y][d.<0.05, :]
   end
vect (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time vect(x, y, a, b)
elapsed time: 3.7118e-5 seconds (37216 bytes allocated)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.978099  0.0405639
 0.94757   0.0224974

julia> @time vect(x, y, a, b)
elapsed time: 7.1977e-5 seconds (37216 bytes allocated)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.978099  0.0405639
 0.94757   0.0224974

julia> @time devect(x, y, a, b)
elapsed time: 1.7146e-5 seconds (376 bytes allocated)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.978099  0.0405639
 0.94757   0.0224974

julia> @time devect(x, y, a, b)
elapsed time: 1.3065e-5 seconds (376 bytes allocated)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.978099  0.0405639
 0.94757   0.0224974

julia> @time devect(x, y, a, b)
elapsed time: 1.8059e-5 seconds (376 bytes allocated)
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.978099  0.0405639
 0.94757   0.0224974
```

There may be faster ways to do the devect solution but notice the difference in bytes allocated.  If a devectorized solution allocates more memory than a vectorized solution, it's probably wrong (at least in Julia).

Comment: Thanks! I removed the a = [a; b] approach from the function, and my devect() now runs a few times faster than the vect().

By the way, is there a way to push! a vector at the end of another vector?

Comment: the append! function may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, I can't figure out how your function only allocated 376 bytes. I copy-pasted your function, and I get:

elapsed time: 0.012100854 seconds (197856 bytes allocated)

Comment: I only timed one execution but in your code you accumulate the timings of 1000.  The input arrays are also random so I wouldn't anticipate the same results.

Comment: Well, I ran several times (n=1 each time), and most of the times, it gives some small number of bytes, just like in your examples, but once in a while, the number for the new devect() function shoots up to higher than the vect() ones.

Answer (score 12):

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables

Your code uses non-constant globals everywhere, which means that you're basically back in the performance realm of interpreted languages since no guarantees can be made at compile time about their type. For a quick speedup, just prefix all your global variables assignments with `const`.

Answer (score 3):

You devectorized code is not very efficient.

I made the following changes:

- Made all the global variables constant
- I preallocated the output vector, rather than appending each time
- I show two different ways you could have devectorized the output in a more straightforward way

  ```
  const x = rand(500)
  const y = rand(500)
  const a = rand()
  const b = rand()

  function devect()
      dist = Array(Float64, 500)

      for i in 1:500
          dist[i] = sqrt((x[i] - a)^2 + (y[i] - b)^2)
      end

      return [x y][dist .< 0.05,:]
  end

  function devect2()
      pairs = Array(Float64, 500, 2)

      for i in 1:500
          dist = sqrt((x[i] - a)^2 + (y[i] - b)^2)
          if dist < 0.05
              pairs[i,:] = [x[i], y[i]]
          end
      end

      return pairs
  end

  function vect()
      d = sqrt((x-a).^2 + (y-b).^2)
      return [x y][d .< 0.05,:]
  end

  using DataFrames

  function df_vect()
      df = DataFrame(x=x, y=y)
      dist = sqrt((df[:x]-a).^2 + (df[:y]-b).^2)

      return df[dist .< 0.05,:]
  end

  const n = 10^3

  @time for i in [1:n] devect() end
  @time for i in [1:n] devect2() end
  @time for i in [1:n] vect() end
  @time for i in [1:n] df_vect() end
  ```

The output is

```
elapsed time: 0.009283872 seconds (16760064 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.003116157 seconds (8456064 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.050070483 seconds (37248064 bytes allocated, 44.50% gc time)
elapsed time: 0.0566218 seconds (30432064 bytes allocated, 40.35% gc time)
```