# Julia: performance of matrix multiplication vs for loop

Tags: for-loop, julia, vectorization

I am puzzled about the superior performance of matrix multiplication versus for loop in my application. Similar questions have been asked a few times on StackOverflow already (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928502/julia-vectorized-vs-devectorized-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65468832/does-julia-need-vectorization-to-speed-up-computation)), but I couldn't get to the bottom of it with the provided answers.

Here's a script to reproduce my problem (using Julia 1.7.3)

```
# Packages and seeds
using Optim, BenchmarkTools, Random
Random.seed!(1704)

# Parameters
N   = 10
M   = 11
σ   = 3.0
ID1 = repeat(1:N, inner = M)
ID2 = repeat(1:M, inner = N)
A   = rand(N * M)
w   = rand(M)
dv  = dummyvar(ID2)
x0  = ones(N*M)

# Function 1
function function_1(x, dv, w, A, σ) 
    c   = dv * w ./ A
    s   = x.^(1-σ) ./ (dv * (dv' * x.^(1-σ)))
    el  = σ*(1 .- s) .+ s
    p   = (c.*el) ./ (el .- 1)
    return sum(abs2.(x .- p))  
end

# Function 2
function function_2(x, dv, w, A, M, ID2, σ)     
    f   = 0.0
    for m = 1:M
        c    = w[m] ./ A[ID2 .== m]
        s    = x[ID2 .== m].^(1-σ) ./ sum(x[ID2 .== m].^(1-σ))
        el   = σ*(1 .- s) .+ s
        f    += sum(abs2.(x[ID2 .== m] .- (c.*el) ./ (el .- 1)))
    end
    return f 
end
```

and `dummyvar` is a function that creates a matrix of indices from a vector (similar to the [Matlab dummyvar function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dummyvar.html))

```
function dummyvar(input_mat::Vector)
    
    # Initialize
    n1  = length(input_mat)
    n2  = length(unique(input_mat))

    # Preallocate output
    mat = zeros(n1, n2)

    # Fill in output
    for i in 1:length(unique(input_mat))
        mat[:,i] = input_mat .== unique(input_mat)[i]
    end

    # Return
    return mat

end
```

Here are the benchmark results for `function_1`

[image]

and here are those of `function_2`

[image]

`function_1` allocates significantly less memory and takes less to execute than `function_2`. However, **I expected to find the opposite pattern** since `function_1` uses matrix multiplication to compute `c` and `s` whereas `function_2` uses loops. I wonder if pre-allocating `f` every time  `function_2` is called explains the difference.

Can `function_2` be rewritten to outperform `function_1` in terms of execution time and memory allocation?

Comment: When micro-optimizing for speed use `@inbound `and `@simd` in your code. Of course use the properly :)

Answer (score 2):

take this for example

```
w[m] ./ A[ID2 .== m]
```

this allocates the following intermediate arrays

1. `ID2 .== m`
2. `A[ID2 .== m]`
3. `w[m] ./ A[ID2 .== m]`

3 is irreducible because you need this for `c`, but 1 and 2 are not.

Apply this logic to each item in your for-loop.

Comment: Thanks. Do you see a way to avoid these steps (beyond what I do in ```function_1```?)